# Marginal Profit?

Tags: calculus

Here is what I am working on;
[image: example]
!

I am really confused because there is not a great explanation of this in my book, and from what I can find in videos and examples, to find marginal profit you take the derivative of profit and go from there, but nothing I work out comes to anything near 50k!

So an explanation of how to find marginal profit would be super helpful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The marginal profit is $P'(x)$ - it denotes the change in the profit when you produce and sell one more car. Hence, as your book tells you, you should look at $P(60)+P'(60)$.

But note that this is only an approximation to the true value you are looking for, which is $P(61)$, since $P(60)+P'(60)=P(60)+\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{P(60+h)-P(60)}{h}\approxeq P(60)+\frac{P(60+1)-P(60)}{1}=P(61)$.

Comment: I appreciate your help, so thank you! Unfortunately I am still completely and utterly confused by it! :(

Comment: Compute $P'(x)$, plug in $x=60$ and then compute $P(60)+P'(60)$. Finished.

Comment: OH!!!! GOT IT THANK YOU :D